# Apache Reverse Proxy - Stop Trailing Slash Redirection

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, webserver, apache2, mod-proxy

I'm migrating a site running static HTML on a Sun One (iPlanet) 6.1 to a Drupal site on Apache.

There is a requirement to keep the old server running and serving old content until it can be moved into Drupal.  I figured the easiest way is to have some reverse proxy entries in Apache that point to this old content.

Here is what I have in the httpd.conf at the server context level.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite_log"
RewriteRule offices/ist/?(.*)$ http://oldserver/offices/ist/$1 [P]
<Location /offices/ist/>
ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>
```

When I make a request like this everything works OK.

```
http://newserver/offices/ist/somedir/
```

If I make the same request (without the trailing slash) it 302 redirects using the old server's name.

```
http://newserver/offices/ist/somedir    =>  Redirect to http://oldserver/offices/ist/somedir/
```

Shouldn't Apache catch this redirect before it's sent back to the client?

Can I get Apache to rewrite these requests before they're sent to the old server?

Comment: The title of your question is `Stop Trailing Slash Redirection` so why a redirection with a trailing slash is OK and one without it is not? Do you want to pass the trailing slash when present in the incoming URI, do you want to add it if not present, do you want to remove it, what?

Comment: @faa The redirection is coming from Sun One webserver.  When it sees a request for a directory *without* a trailing slash it sends a redirect to the same URI with a a trailing slash.  The Apache proxy is not catching this redirect, so the hostname is not rewritten to the proxy hostname.  I want Apache proxy to catch the redirect request.

Comment: The problem is a result of Sun One's redirection headers.  Proxying to an Apache server, the problem goes away.  Apache is able to catch the redirection sent by the backend Apache server before it is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but may be `(.*)` it too greedy.

I had a look at the [Apache mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) but I did not find an example with `?`.

I would suggest to try it without the `/?` or with something similar to the [Apache mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) example.

```
ProxyPass /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo http://foo.example.com/bar
```

Comment: @faa: I know. But I'm not sure about the precedence.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is a result of Sun One's redirection headers.
Proxying Apache to another Apache server, the problem goes away. Apache is able to catch the redirection sent by the backend Apache server before it is sent to the client.